# Insert dynamic data in phonegap sqlite?

Tags: sqlite, cordova

I have developed one app using phonegap. I want to insert the data using the phonegap sqlite. I have got the bulk of data from server using web service. Now I want to insert the service response data into local database.

```
for(var i=0;i<serviceResponse.length;i++) 
{   
    var insertQuery = "";
    insertQuery = "INSERT INTO PREFERENCE(ID,NAME,TYPE,VALUE,ISFAVORITE,RANK) VALUES (" + "'" + serviceResponse[i].prefid + "','" + serviceResponse[i].name + "','" + serviceResponse[i].type+ "','" + serviceResponse[i].ispreference+ "','" +serviceResponse[i].isfavorite+ "','"+serviceResponse[i].rank + "')" ;
    dbinsert.transaction(function insertUserPrefDB(tx){ 
    tx.executeSql(insertQuery);     
      },errorCB);   
    if(i==(serviceResponse.length-1))   
    { 
        alert("Pref Inserted Successfully");                
    }
}
```

What is my problem here is,

This code will insert the last record in local database. If the service response having 10 records that time the local db also having 10 records but all records are same (i.e.last record return from service).
Please help me.

Comment: Can you post your code here?

Comment: Facing the same problem :( did you get the solution for it

Comment: Ya..I have got the solution using recursive function.

Comment: Please post your solution looking for this to solve mine, mine duplicate entries been posted to db @Lavanya